# programatically add textview inside recyclerview onbindView adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

On scrolling the `RecyclerView` the data inside the `TextView` changes even though the data in the array  `logtime.get(i).getTime()` does not change.it changes only when we place the data inside textview which is generating dynamically.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(PunchCardViewHolder holder, int position) {

    PunchCardReport punchCardReport = punchCardReports.get(position);
    holder.sNumber.setText(punchCardReport.getmSNumber());
    holder.logDate.setText(punchCardReport.getmLogDate());
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(punchCardReport.getmLogTime(), ",");
    List<LogTime> logtime = punchCardReport.getmLogTimeList();
    for (int i = 0; i < logtime.size(); i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: "+logtime.get(i).getTime());

    }
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams dim = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     for (int i = 0; i < logtime.size(); i++) {

         TextView textView=new TextView(mContext);
         textView.setLayoutParams(dim);
         textView.setText(logtime.get(i).getTime());//the problem is here when we put data inside textview
         holder.logTime.addView(textView);
    }

}
    @Override
    public int getItemCount () {
        return punchCardReports.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your design is completely wrong. You are creating new `TextView`s on every call to `onBindViewHolder()` which means when you *scroll* back to a view a fresh list of `TextView`s are created, so now you have two sets of `TextView`s one from last call and one from now (Keep scrolling and there will be more extra `TextViews` attached).

Creating new Views should be done in `onCreateViewHolder()`. The reason you are getting this behavior could be because `RecyclerView` uses `Scrapped Views`, which means that it reuses the `View`s created earlier. Thus enhancing performance (because no new memory allocations are required). If you are looking for a Nested `RecyclerView` then do that instead.

Comment: yes agree. this can cause memory leakage or other performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can add following code in onBindViewHolder.

```
if(holder.logTime.getChildCount()>0){
    holder.logTime.removeAllViews();
}

for (int i = 0; i < logtime.size(); i++) {

    TextView textView=new TextView(mContext);
    textView.setLayoutParams(dim);
    textView.setText(logtime.get(i).getTime());
    //the problem is here when we put data inside textview
    holder.logTime.addView(textView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Put this line in starting of onbindViewHolder.

holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

Or, you can put your TextView inside XML file. There is no need to create dynamic textview inside Onbinder.

Comment: This solution can cause memory issue. You should create XML for text view and other view. Creating view Inside OnBindViewHolder() is not recommended. If you want, I give you demo source code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You just add holder.setIsRecyclable(false); inside method onBindViewHolder in your Adapter